# Mixing NFSv4 all_squash and sshfs access

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, sshfs

I have a problem with my server. In my internal network I hand out several network shares using NFSv4 from a Debian Squeeze server to my clients. These shares use the `all_squash` option because I want all users to be able to read and write to the share without any permission hassle.

But now I also need to grant someone outside my network access to one of these shares. Usually I'd use sshfs for something like this, but I'm running into a problem. All the files are owned by nobody:nobody and have permission 644.

What's the easiest or best way to grant someone from outside my network access to these files? Aside from turning to a complicated setup like a NFS over VPN or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sshfs` has `-o uid=N` `-o gid=N` and `-o umask=xxxx` options, as well as `-o idmap=[none,user]` (for handling how the UID space is mapped).  I believe these will do what you need.

The [sshfs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs) may be of some help, but for details on how these options work you'll probably need to peruse the source code -- the man page is pretty awful...

Comment: Does that mean that I need to set a valid password for user `nobody` and have the external client use the credentials for the `nobody` account to connect?

Comment: no, but you will need to establish some way for `nobody` to log in (e.g. via SSH keys) for this to work...

Comment: Okay thanks. I ended up using your suggestion in combination with a new user on the server and the `anonuid`/`anongid` options for NFS.